# Visual Studio 2015 JavaScript Language Service stuck in an infinite loop of downloading non-existing referenced files

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, visual-studio-2015

I have an Ionic project in Visual Studio 2015 which uses Firebase. After opening the project, de JavaScript language service starts to download some "referenced file" from `https://auth.firebase.com/`, only gets gibberish but keeps trying to download the same thing over and over again, CPU heat going crazy meanwhile. See image. Any ideas how to break out of this infinite loop?

[image]

Comment: I had visual studio do this to me the other day using an asp.net mvc project, restarting visual studio solved it though

Comment: Restart didn't solve it to me. Neither VS nor complete Windows restart.

Comment: You could manually stop the service which is using your CPU(probably the one trying to download the file) from Task Manager and download the referenced file yourself. Hopefully, it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I checked with our language service team and this is a known issue in VS 2013 / 2015. The problem is that your project runs some code to authenticate with Firebase, and that code ends up doing some dynamic evaluation that adds a script element to the DOM.

The VS language service runs this code every time it does an evaluation for intellisense, which happens frequently while you are typing. This causes the CPU and memory to spike.

We have a bug to track this and are working on a solution. In the meantime, you can probably mitigate the issue by commenting out the authentication code while you're developing.

Sorry for the trouble. Hope that helps.

UPDATE: you might be able to temporarily fix the issue by adding a new `DWORD` registry value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\JavaScriptLanguageService` called `MaximumScriptLoaderReferencesToLoad` with a value of 0.

Comment: Many thanks Michael, your registry setting just saved my CPU from melting! When the bug is fixed, can you add a comment here so we will know we can remove that setting?

Comment: I'm glad that fixed the problem. I expect the bug to be fixed as part of update 1, but I will try to circle back here and update the thread later on.

Comment: This worked for me too, looks like it's trying to connect with email auth but with Angular any reference to my auth service was causing this crazy output loop and driving me nuts.

Here is the line from my log if it helps: https://auth.firebase.com/v2//auth/password?&email=undefined&password=undefined&v=js-2.2.2&transport=json&suppress_status_codes=true&callback=__firebase_auth_jsonp.fn144486245066182453

Comment: didn't helped for me (vs2013 express) :(

Comment: @Sag1v - It's possible that this solution doesn't work in VS 2013. We only looked at the 2015 codebase (disclosure: I work for Microsoft).

Comment: got it. any chance you can help me get it to work with vs2013 community?

Comment: Even if there is a workaround, there are no plans to update 2013 at this time. If we do ship a fix, it will be in 2015.

Comment: Do you put the entire value as "DWORD 0:" or just "0". Because the value is zero already.

Comment: This isn't clear to me. Add a new DWORD (32-bit) Value with name as "DWORD 0:" and data as 0? I've tried this, I've tried adding just name = DWORD and data = 0 and also DWORD 0 and data = 0. All in VS2015. Didn't work

Comment: @MichaelBraude do you have any update on when a fix to VS might be pushed for this? I've added the recommended work around, but would prefer to have the working version, obviously.

Comment: @Mukus @usefulBee -- If you haven't figured this out yet, in regedit, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...\JSLS (shortened, obviously), add a new DWORD called `MaximumScriptLoaderReferencesToLoad`, value set to 0.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi, it should have been fixed in vs update 1. Is it still reproing for you? Did you install update 1?

Comment: I am on update one, though perhaps I'm not seeing the *exact* same issue. What I am seeing is my editor hanging when I'm editing script files while the JSLS tries to do something, though I'm not sure what. Using the workaround here seemed to fix that, not sure if it's the same situation or not.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi Thanks for that. But it got so annoying that I swithced to webstorm. It's much better suited to what I'm doing and intellisense and speed of build is just much better.

Comment: This is my first foray into web dev in VS, and I too am leaning towards doing it externally. A lot of the tooling seems like it could be nice, but has so far just been a pain.

Comment: Still a problem in vs 2015 professional. I added the key to registry but it didn't fix it. still the same error, and it freezes the whole visual studio. Have to kill the devenv.exe every time.

Comment: Have the same issue. Nothing that I find solves the issue. Fix this!

Comment: @MichaelBraude I've updated to Update 2, I added the DWORD, and I still have issues reproducing. It hangs and hangs and really hangs...

Comment: Hi everybody, sorry for the trouble. I've sent this to the language service team and they are investigating, although I think this is actually a different issue. Please make sure you take every update to visual studio since we are issuing patches to fix issues like this one.

Comment: @MichaelBraude I've taken today vs2015 update 2 and still the same issue. I just installed vs2015 and going to install it again. I'll post my findings after it's installed

Comment: @MichaelBraude same issue, but just to clarify things, for me it's not downloading stuff, it just gets stuck and it says `The javascript language service is processing your request in the background` and also in the output window i get `The smart indent request was cancelled because it did not complete within 250 ms`. If I clear `_references.js`, it works ok, but then no more intellisense. I also have vs2013 installed and in there i do not have this issue.

Answer (score -3):

Just close VS and restart it as Administrator. Hope this resolve the problem.