# VS2015: Prevent download of dynamically generated JavaScript reference by "JavaScript Language Service"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Please see the below image.. note the timestamps -- my computer does not like this activity.  This problem seems to happen whenever I have any *.js or *.cshtml file open.

I have turned off "Download remote references (e.g. http://) for files in the miscellaneous files project" in JavaScript -> IntelliSense -> General, but the problem continues.

I also tried moving the inclusion of "doorbell.io.js" into a bundle rather than the _Layout.cshtml file, but that didn't work.

How can I prevent VS from downloading this JavaScript reference?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To fix the immediate issue**

Remove the offending line from "_references.js".  Save.  The problem should stop immediately.

`/// <reference path="doorbell.io.js" />`

**Future considerations...**

Note that by default references are set to auto-sync.  This means that if you ever refresh your sources, such as from nuget or by adding a javascript file manually, the offending file could be added back in.  You can disable this functionality by right-clicking inside the file and unselecting `Auto-sync JavaScript References`

[image]

If you decide to disable this feature, you can still manually update them with the `Update JavaScript References` menu item.

*Note that at this point in time there is no easy way to prevent a specific file from re-appearing on this list.  You will need to remove it manually every time Visual Studio generates this list on your behalf.*

Comment: I'm getting a similar message for code that references firebase. When you say "remove from _references.js" where is this file? Or did you mean remove the reference from my file?

Comment: @DennisSmolek the default location in an MVC app is `~/Scripts/_references.js`.  If you don't see it there you can also try Edit -> Navigate To... (Ctrl + ,) and search by file name.

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase Auth Does the Same Thing**
I had a hard time solving this for my application when I switched from 2013 to 2015.

I'm using firebase/angular and any file that referenced my Auth service caused this loop. What ended up solving it was adding this registry item as a DWORD with a value of 0: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\JavaScriptLanguageService\MaximumScriptLoaderReferencesToLoad`

All credit goes to Michael Braude with Firebase from this SO: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752643/visual-studio-2015-javascript-language-service-stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-of-down)