# Can't stop Visual Studio 2015 lagging for seconds in JS files saying "JavaScript language service is processing your request in the background..."?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide, editor, visual-studio-2015

In the status-bar when I am typing in a Js file it shows this message on keyup and editor hangs for 2 or 3 seconds. This probably **started happening suddenly When I moved some Js files into category folders** but I am not sure this is the cause. I dont know what is the problem. Before the problem all js files were in a same folder like angular files and my own app files. 

I also tried uninstalling the [WebCompiler](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler) extension and resetting the visual studio from Import & Export Settings and hard resetting through `devenv /ResetSettings` command.

[image]

I have also applied this answer : [Visual Studio 2015 JavaScript Language Service stuck in an infinite loop of downloading non-existing referenced files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752643/visual-studio-2015-javascript-language-service-stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-of-down)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I stopped the lagging by editing _references.js and setting autosync enabled="false" and removing a ton of 3rd-party (angular, ionic) library files from the listed references.

```
<autosync enabled="false" />
```

to the top of _references.js file

Comment: Thanks for the discovery :-) I don't need intellisense with lagging. I have deleted that file altogether and its working like a charm. :)

Comment: @Hani check deleting _.reference.js

Comment: I found that setting autosync = false was not enough.  There were over 600 different files listed in _references.js .   I deleted about 450 of those and now performance is fine.   I was getting 4 and 5 second lags and this is not really a slow computer.  Now with autosync = false the file will not be repopulated and I would rather that then these huge lags.

Answer (score 6):

If previous answer is not clear enough or tl;dr

add

```
/// <autosync enabled="false" />
```

to the top of _references.js file

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I have installed the latest updates but the problem remained. Then, I disabled the 3rd party add-ons one by one. It now works without any problems. It is clear that some 3rd party add-ons have bugs causes visual studio malfunctioning.

Hope it works.

Comment: May be but in my case (questioner) it doesn't lag in other projects then the one due to which I posted the above question. I suspect some bug in visual studio which can't handle JavaScript files especially like Angularjs 3rd party modules because my project is using a large number of them.

Comment: i'm having the same problems.  what add-ons did you remove?

Comment: May be you can open Visual Studio in safe mode to understand if your case is regarding with the add-ons or not.