# JavaScript Language is Loading In The Back Ground and Vs 2015 is lagging then sometimes Restart

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

when i start to writing in Java script files visual studio hanging for Seconds, And When i want to include files to my project restart suddenly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to  (  _references.js ) and UnComment this

```
 <autosync enabled="true" />
```

and edit it to be :

```
<autosync enabled="false" />
```

for more info:
 [Can't stop Visual Studio 2015 lagging for seconds in JS files saying "JavaScript language service is processing your request in the background..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540028/cant-stop-visual-studio-2015-lagging-for-seconds-in-js-files-saying-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Bro For Helping